# Not able to Hide controls using setHidden property from another class?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, xcode, hidden

I am invoking PickerView from Employee View.

Following is code in my didSelect method of tableView in Employee class.

```
pickView = [[PickerView alloc] initWithNibName:@"PickerView" bundle:nil];
[pickView.pickerView setHidden:YES];
[pickView.datePicker setHidden:YES];
switch (indexPath.row)
{
    case 0:
        pickView.pickerArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithObjects:@"ML",@"M",@"M SL",@"ME",@"ME SL",@"S",@"SB",@"SH",@"ST",@"S SL",@"SH SL",@"ST SL",@"ND",@"CAE",@"EDW",@"NSW", nil];
        pickView.title = @"Select Taxcode";
        [pickView.pickerView setHidden:NO];
        break;
    case 1:
        [pickView.datePicker setHidden:NO];
        pickView.title = @"Pay Period";
        break;
    default:
        break;
}
[self.navigationController pushViewController:pickView animated:YES];
```

I am not able to see the controls in PickerView. I have kept all controls Hidden from IB. Now when I click 1st cell in Employee's table View then only 1 control should be visible.

What could be the problem?

Comment: check if connections are set in IB.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this code in Switch case. Le me know if you still have some problems with this.

```
switch (indexPath.row)
{
    case 0:
    {
        pickView.pickerArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithObjects:@"ML",@"M",@"M SL",@"ME",@"ME SL",@"S",@"SB",@"SH",@"ST",@"S SL",@"SH SL",@"ST SL",@"ND",@"CAE",@"EDW",@"NSW", nil];
        pickView.title = @"Select Taxcode";
        [pickView.pickerView setHidden:NO];
        break;
     }
    case 1:
    {
        [pickView.datePicker setHidden:NO];
        pickView.title = @"Pay Period";
        break;
    } 
    default:
        break;
}
```

Comment: @DShah: Then I suppose the problem lies somewhere else. Also please try making it unhidden from XIB as you already making it hidden programmatically before switch case statements. May be this way you may recognize where exactly your problem lies.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure about the exact issue but I think you can try putting your switch case after you push the view controller.

Or use some booleans to pass to the view controller and then in the viewDidAppear of PickerView process your hide / show for the controls

Comment: i tried the first one but no success. For 2nd option I have 9 such case and there are lots of variables already, I dont want to do that option..